# I need help tagging articles in a way that doesn't slow down the database

Tags: database, tags, related-entries

I have an article-based site that runs slowly, and I would like to change that.

First, each article has 3 options for tags in the backend (we use this add-on: http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/). The 3 tag options are primary (mandatory), secondary, and company (if the article mentions a particular company). Also, for each article there is a "related articles" section on the frontend, which is generated based on that article's tag(s). This complicated tagging structure I think is unnecessary, and hard on the database (right)?

Second, each article is cached. This slows down the site and is also hard on the database.

So, what would you suggest I do to speed up my website and find "related articles" in a smart, simple way? Is there another add-on you would suggest, or should I stick with Solspace's Tags?

Thanks.

Here's my code:

{if embed:primaryTag != ""}

{embed:primaryTag} in the News

{exp:tag:entries limit="4" tag="{embed:primaryTag}" dynamic="off" tag_group_name="default|primary_tag" websafe_separator="" status="open|imported" disable="pagination|member_data|categories|custom_fields"}

- {title}

{if count == "4"} More on {embed:primaryTag} 
{/if} 
{/exp:tag:entries} 
{/if}

Comment: Could you possibly post the code you are using on the template to get the related articles? I don't think the structure is at fault here, maybe you just need to tweak it.

Comment: {if embed:primaryTag != ""}
<hr />
<h5>{embed:primaryTag} in the News</h5>
<div class="pad4"></div>
{exp:tag:entries  limit="4" tag="{embed:primaryTag}" dynamic="off" tag_group_name="default|primary_tag" websafe_separator="_" status="open|imported" disable="pagination|member_data|categories|custom_fields"}
<ul>
 <li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
</ul>
{if count == "4"}
<a href="/topic/tag/{exp:replace_plus find=":SPACE:" replace="_"}{embed:primaryTag}{/exp:replace_plus}">More on {embed:primaryTag}</a>
{/if}
{/exp:tag:entries}
{/if}

Comment: It would be best to update your original question with the template code so that it can be formatted as a code block.

Comment: How are you determining that the tagging is what is slowing the site down? I'm also confused by your statement that the caching is 'hard on the database' - cached articles should be loaded from the cache, not needing the database?

Comment: Are you actually using embeds? I recommend posting the entire template if possible so we can see the entries loop from within which the relationship to the three different tag fields is established. It sounds like just some optimization may be needed.